# Mozilla "invalid security certificate"

Tags: firefox, ssl-certificate

From behind my network in the office Firefox has a consistent problem of delivering.

> "***** uses an invalid security certificate."

[image]

IE navigates with out any problems.

I assume this is from an upstream network security, forcing HTTPS?  Is there a work around to this?

Comment: Please provide the entire chain of certificates or at least a screenshot of it.

Comment: This is most likely that your office network is performing a MITM attack on you, so they can monitor your https traffic. However, you'll need to provide the entire chain of certificates, as Daniel B suggests, to confirm this.

Comment: IE and Firefox do not share the same certificate store.  The fact you are getting an error with Firefox and not IE indicates you have a proxy and a MiTM certificate setup going on.  This can either be harmless ( i.e. on purpose ) or hostile that is entirely up to you to figure out.  Without critical information about the chain we can't answer this question.